# One Click Install - Dgraph - Gru

Tags: graph-databases, dgraph

I installed dgraph gru for interviews

```
go get github.com/dgraph-io/gru
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/dgraph-io/gru
git checkout develop
go build . && ./gru -user=admin -pass=pass -secret=0a45e5eGseF41o0719PJ39KljMK4F4v2
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8088:8080 -p 127.0.0.1:9080:9080 -v ~/dgraph:/dgraph --name dgraph dgraph/dgraph:v0.7.5 dgraph --bindall=true
```

I'm getting below error when i try to create quiz or questions

```
Aug 09 10:14:23  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.001305978s
Aug 09 10:14:24  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000762875s
Aug 09 10:19:40  gru[16999]: Error while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeout[negroni] Started POST /api/admin/add-question
Aug 09 10:20:10  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.001419475s
Aug 09 10:20:17  gru[16999]: [negroni] Started POST /api/admin/get-all-questions
Aug 09 10:20:31  gru[16999]: [negroni] Started GET /api/admin/get-all-tags
Aug 09 10:20:43  gru[16999]: [negroni] Started GET /api/admin/get-all-tags
Aug 09 10:20:47  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000821271s
Aug 09 10:21:01  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000790588s
Aug 09 10:21:13  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000748794s
Aug 09 11:12:24  gru[16999]: Error while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeoutError while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeoutError while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeoutError while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeoutError while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeout[negroni] Started POST /api/admin/get-all-questions
Aug 09 11:12:54  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000807257s
Aug 09 11:13:10  gru[16999]: [negroni] Started GET /api/admin/get-all-tags
Aug 09 11:13:41  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000734698s
Aug 09 11:16:56  gru[16999]: Error while rejecting candidates: Couldn't get response from Dgraph: Post http://localhost:8088/query: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: i/o timeout[negroni] Started POST /api/admin/add-question
Aug 09 11:17:26  gru[16999]: [negroni] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30.000777429s
```

I tried with different versions of dgraph database.

Is there any scripts or docker to install it on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

From the logs I can see that it is not able to connect to Dgraph. Thats because docker is exposing port `8088` whereas Gru server expects Dgraph to be running on `8080`. You can run Dgraph like

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080  -v ~/dgraph:/dgraph dgraph/dgraph:v0.7.5 dgraph --bindall=true
```

You also have to run Gru server and caddy as mentioned in the README. Now that I think about it the UI doesn't need to be run separately from the Gru web server. I can try adding a one-step quick install guide over the weekend.